# understanding a proof about an uncountable metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

> See the proof below about why a complete metric space with no isolated points must be uncountable.

[image]

I don't quite understand why $y\neq x_n$ for any $n$. I think it might be possible to show this if I can show $y_n\neq x_i$ for any $1\leq i\leq n,$ but do to this, I found it easier to use the additional condition that $x_i\not\in \overline{B}_{r_n}(y_n)$ for any $1\leq i\leq n.$

To clarify, I need to satisfy $y_n \in \overline{B}_{r_{n-1}}(y_{n-1}),y_n\neq x_n$ and $\overline{B}_{r_n}(y_n)\subseteq B_{r_{n-1}}(y_{n-1})$ and $0<r_n < \frac{1}n$ and $x_n\not\in \overline{B}_{r_n}(y_n)$.

And finally, aren't all the open balls of $X$ infinite?

Comment: This actually relies on the choice of the radii $r_i$. The Cauchy sequence $(y_n)$ cannot converge to $x_1$ because it lives in $B_{r_2}(y_2)$ which does not contain $x_1$. Similarly, for all $x_k$, the radius $r_{k+1}$ is chosen so that $(y_n)$ lives eventually at a fixed distance from $x_k$, and therefore cannot converge to $x_k$. As $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ is an exhaustive list of $X$, $y$ cannot be in $X$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I think the textbook failed to mention that we also need $x_2\not\in \bar B_{r_2}(y_2)$ and in general $x_n\not\in \bar B_{r_n}(y_n)$...... Then $y\ne x_n$ because $y\in  \bar B_{r_n}(y_n).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that each open ball $B_r(z)$ must contain more than one point: If $B_r(z)$ were a singleton, then $B_r(z) =\{z\}$ so that $z$ would be an isolated point. You can use this to show that all open balls $B_r(z)$ are *infinite*, but that is irrelevant for the argument.

Your book recursively constructs $y_n \in X$ and $r_n \in (0,\frac 1 n)$ such that

1. $y_n \ne x_n$
2. $\bar B_{r_{n+1}}(y_{n+1}) \subset B_{r_n}(y_n)$

but **misses to say** that we also want to have

3. $x_n \notin  \bar B_{r_n}(y_n)$.

The third condition is mentioned only for $n = 1$.

The recursive construction is based on the above-mentioned fact: We can always choose $y_{n+1} \in B_{r_n}(y_n)$ such that $y_{n+1} \ne x_{n+1}$. Given $y_{n+1}$, we can choose $r_{n+1} \in (0, \frac 1 {n+1})$ such that 2. and 3. are satisfied.

So why is $y \ne x_n$ for all $n$? Assume $y = x_n$ for some $n$. Then $y \notin \bar B_{r_n}(y_n)$ by 3. This is a contradiction because $y_k \in  \bar B_{r_n}(y_n)$ for $k \ge n$ which implies $y \in \bar B_{r_n}(y_n)$.

Comment: just to confirm, couldn't you just use the fact that $y_i\neq x_k$ for any $1\leq k\leq i$ and then if $y=x_k$ for some $k$ then $|y_n-y| \geq |y_n-x_k| > 0$ for $n\geq k$?